# Getting the second dataset from an OLE DB Source in SSIS

Tags: ssis, oledb, database-metadata, fmtonly

I need to read data from a DB1 and write them to another DB2.
I use a complex query with CTEs and temp tables and no, i can't put this query in a SProc.
I use an OLE DB source and an OLE DB Destination.

When i put the query as SQL Command in the OLEDBSource I get the usual complaint about not being able to determine metadata because a CTE is using a temp table.

I can't use the "with result sets" workaround because it is not a SProc. So i try with the other workaround, the "SET FMTONLY ON/OFF" .

Now the OLE DB Source accepts my query but it outputs two datasets, the first empty and the second is the data I need. The OLE DB Destination doesn't write a single row because it is reading only the first resultset, the empty one.

How can i solve this?

I cannot change the temp tables in something else and basically i can't change the query. I am looking for a SSIS solution if possible, not a SQL solution.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an SSIS solution, you cannot use an OLE DB Source.   That component can only access the first result set.

What you can do is use a Script Transformation as your data source, and access the second result set in the usual way, and send its columns to the output of the script.

Comment: I am not expert enough in SSIS to understand what you wrote. Do you mean that i have to use a Script Transformation (ST) INSTEAD of the OLEDBSource and write in this ST a C# code that actually goes on the DB to retrieve data, put in in a dataset that will have 2 tables and then take the second table and send it to the OLEDB destination?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.